# Can't see Bottom Sheet inside fragment

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I have a viewpager which have several fragments inside. I want to add a bottom sheet to one of the fragments. Lets call it report_fragment.
The layouts for the fragment and the bottom sheet are:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl">

    <include layout="@layout/report_page_content" />

    <!-- include the bottom sheet -->
    <iclude layout="@layout/report_bottom_sheet_table" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**report_page_content layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/report_page_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

**bottom sheet layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/report_bottom_sheet"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:behavior_hideable="true"
    app:behavior_peekHeight="120dp"
    android:background="@color/report_bottom_sheet_bck_color"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/daily_bs_tests"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The java code for fragment is:

```
    public class FragmentReportPage extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.report_page_content, container, false);

        // Init other views ....

        // LinearLayout bottomSheetLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.report_bottom_sheet);

        // If i uncomment below line, an exception will arise
        // BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetLayout);
        // bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);

        return v;
    }
```

Unfortunately, no bottom sheet is shown in the fragment. What i have done wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha09'
```

style

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Mainactivity.java

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ViewPager mPager;


    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
        pagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }

    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new ItemFragment();
                default:
                    return new ItemFragment();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/vpPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

ItemFragment.java

```
public class ItemFragment extends Fragment {

    View view;
    BottomSheetBehavior behavior;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_list, container, false);
        LinearLayout bottomSheet = view.findViewById(R.id.botttomsheet);
        behavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
        behavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {

            }
        });
        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS));

        return view;
    }

}
```

fragment_item_list.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:name="com.andy.faceread.fragment.ItemFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".fragment.ItemFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/fragment_item" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/botttomsheet"
        app:behavior_hideable="false"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="bottomsheet"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: The strange thing was when i removed the report_page_content and bottom_sheet_layout and merge them in the fragment layout all the problems gone!